# Angle between vectors $\vec a + \vec b$ and $\vec c$?

Tags: vectors, inner-products

If there are three vector $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ provided, what is the angle between $\vec a + \vec b$ and $\vec c$? I understand how to calculate for angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, $\vec a$ and $\vec c$ and $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ but what does the angle between $\vec a + \vec b$ and $\vec c$ mean?

Comment: Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 7):

You compute the sum of $a+b$, that is a vector, if it helps, you can give a new name, $d$.

Now you can compute the angle between $d$ and $c$ using the formula that you are familiar with.

Answer (score 6):

We have that $\vec d=\vec a+\vec b$ then

$$\cos (\theta)=\frac{\vec d \cdot \vec c}{|\vec d||\vec c|}$$

Answer (score 3):

The important concept to keep in mind here is that when you add two vectors, $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, the result is just another vector. It has a magnitude, a direction (if its magnitude is positive), and components just like any other vector.

We may write the expression 
$\vec a + \vec b$ 
in order to *name* this vector, but that does not make it into any new kind of object. 
The formulas that apply to other vectors still apply.

To find the angle between $\vec a + \vec b$ and $\vec c,$
take the formula you would use for the angle between any two vectors, put  $\vec a + \vec b$ 
in the places where the first vector occurs in the formula,
and put $\vec c$ in the places where the second vector occurs. 
Look at other answers for details of what happens after you do this.

Comment: If vectors a=[1,1,0], b=[3,2,1], and c=[1,0,2], does the mean the angle between a +b and c will be the angle between [4,3,1] and [1,0,2]?

Comment: @bison72 yes, this is how vector addition works.

Answer (score 2):

Just $$\cos(\widehat{\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{c}})=\frac{(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\vec{c}}{|\vec{a}+\vec{b}||\vec{c}|}.$$

Here, $|\vec{a}+\vec{b}|=\sqrt{|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2+2\vec{a}\vec{b}}$ and $(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\vec{c}=\vec{a}\vec{c}+\vec{b}\vec{c}.$

Comment: Why someone down voted?

Comment: Might be because someone thought it's not obvious that e.g. $ab$ is the scalar product of vectors and not simple product of their norms (because you've dropped the arrows used by the OP). But that's just my guess.

Comment: @Ruslan But there is a context. Thank you for your trying! I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition of the scalar product we get
$$
(a+b)\cdot c =
\lVert a+b \rVert \lVert c \rVert \cos \angle(a+b,c)
$$
where $\lVert v \rVert = \sqrt{v\cdot v}$.

For non-zero $a+b$ and $c$ we can solve for the angle
$$
\angle(a+b,c) = \arccos \frac{(a+b)\cdot c}{\lVert a+b \rVert \lVert c \rVert}
$$